# Why it's so slow when I call adapter by tool "Call MobileFirst Adapter"?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When I use the tool "Call Mobilefirst Adapter" provided by MobileFirst studio 7.1, it take about 1 minutes to start up. What cause this? It's very fast on before versions.

Other recommendation:
Please change the test method to old fashon using Url not to generate a file and read the file content, so I can refresh the page when I changed the adapter code. Current fashon take my much more time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is kind of baseless, isn't it? You did not provide any information and code snippets regarding your adapter. What does it do, where is it pointing at, is there any security involved, how much data are you processing and so on... Without this, it is difficult to help.

For example, this may happen if you did not first start the server. If you did not start the server and you attempt to call an adapter procedure the Studio will first start the server, deploy the adapter and only then call the adapter procedure. This *could* take a minute.

As an alternative to Studio you can use a tool such as Postman that will allow you to enter the adapter's REST URL structure and call it again and again and again...